# A dependency is crashing the .exe created with PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

So I have been creating a python script to handle some user access
and need to have this script distributed to the office so that we are all able to use it.

However, when I try to create the .exe file using PyInstaller it completes but somehow it then continues to crash everytime I try to launch the .exe.

I have narrowed the problem down to a dependency, a module called PyCountry.
The module is used to convert a country into the ALPHA3 ISO standard.

If the module is imported the app will crash everytime. 
If the module is not the app will run just fine.

Are there alternatives to PyCountry or a way which I can make it work with PyCountry?
I have already tried adding the path of PyCountry directly into a .spec file but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Four years later! Try --hiden-imports=pycountry on creating the pyinstaller exe